# How does zoomToRect work with UIScrollView and specifying the rect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

If I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView` within it that is 1,000 x 1,000 (and the same `contentSize` on the `UIScrollView`) what does the passed `CGRect` in `zoomToRect` specify?

Say I want it to be zoomed in to the `maximumZoomScale` on a double tap? I understand the `x` and `y` of the rect will be derived from the tap point, but where does the `width` and `height` come from? If I give it 100x100 what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by the Apple documentation:

> This method zooms so that the content view becomes the area defined by rect, adjusting the
>   zoomScale as necessary.

This means that is you make this call:

```
[self.scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(25,25,950,950) animated:YES];
```

You will zoom the scroll view in to show that area completely in the visible area of the scroll view.

Hope this helps.